# "Datatype mismatch" in C# and SQLite code

Tags: c#, sqlite, types, mismatch

[image]

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //string sql = "INSERT INTO Product_details(ID,name,qty,r_rate,W_rate,category,Department,taxable,GST_CLASS,hsn_code,s_packing,M_packing,Max_stock,min_stock,status)VALUES(null,'"+txt_box_P_Name.Text+"', '"+txt_box_qty.Text + "','"+txt_box_RRate.Text + "','"+txt_box_WRate.Text+"','"+com_box_Cat.Text+"','"+txt_depart.Text+"','"+gststatus+"','"+txt_box_GST.Text +"','"+txt_box_hsn.Text+"','"+txt_box_std_package.Text+"','"+txt_box_mas_pack.Text+"','"+txt_box_max_stock.Text+"','"+txt_box_min_stock.Text+"','"+comboBox1.Text+"');";
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Product_details  VALUES(    'NULL',                              '"+txt_box_P_Name.Text+"',                                '"+txt_box_qty.Text+"',                                '"+txt_box_RRate.Text+"',                                '"+txt_box_WRate.Text+"',                                '"+ com_box_Cat.Text + "',                                '"+txt_depart.Text+"',                                '"+txt_box_pur_price.Text+"',                                '"+txt_box_GST.Text+"',                                '"+txt_box_hsn.Text+"',                                '"+txt_box_std_package.Text+"',                                '"+txt_box_mas_pack.Text+"',                                '"+txt_box_max_stock.Text+"',                                '"+txt_box_min_stock.Text+"',                                '"+comboBox1.Text+"'                            );            ";
    try
    {
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        ClearTextBoxes();
        MessageBox.Show("Product Added");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about the table you're inserting into, I can only guess - `'NULL'` is interpreted as 4 characters, which probably isn't what you want. Try using `VALUES (null, ` without the single quotes. Also google SQL injection, if someone enters a single qoute in one of the textboxes your code will break.

Comment: 1. Please don't SHOUT. 2. Please tell us what's going on here in English instead of just posting code. 3. Please don't post screenshots of errors. You could give us the type of the exception and the stack trace, but instead you give us a giant fullscreen screenshot of the string "datatype mismatch" which you already put in your title.

Comment: _PLEASE SEE PICTURE_ No. Please include the details in the body of the post. And please format your code so it's not nearly 1,000 characters long!

Comment: This is bad code, string concatenation for SQL commands is bad. Research how to properly parameterize the query to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: If I had to guess your ID column should be sent 0 not null. But you should be using typed parameters.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
THANKS C.EVENHUIS & ED PLUNKETT

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string sql = "INSERT INTO Product_details  VALUES(NULL,'"+txt_box_P_Name.Text+"','"+txt_box_qty.Text+"','"+txt_box_RRate.Text+"','"+txt_box_WRate.Text+"','"+ com_box_Cat.Text + "','"+txt_depart.Text+"','"+txt_box_pur_price.Text+"','"+txt_box_GST.Text+"','"+txt_box_hsn.Text+"','"+txt_box_std_package.Text+"','"+txt_box_mas_pack.Text+"','"+txt_box_max_stock.Text+"','"+txt_box_min_stock.Text+"','"+comboBox1.Text+"');";
        try
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            ClearTextBoxes();
            MessageBox.Show("Product Added");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }
```